# Django-haystack using rebuild_index command gives error:

Tags: django, django-haystack, xapian

I get this error:

xapian.WritableDatabase_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_WritableDatabase(*args))
xapian.DatabaseOpeningError: /home/xapian/mysite_index: No databases listed

when running the "./manage.py rebuild_index" so that I can populate my index for the first time. I do get the warning message and confirmation to rebuild_index and then I'm presented with a list of information with the last line being the aforementioned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, once I deleted the folder "mysite_index and let it get created automatically when running the "rebuild_index" command, everything worked perfectly.  Thought I was supposed to create that entire directory structure, guess not.